# flutter catching print data after publishing app in closed testing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am printing some strings in console , to check few key points in the app , but one of those key points includes in app purchase and in app purchase can only work when the app i published on playstore either in closed testing or in production mode , my question is , is there any way to catch those print statements after the app is published.
I know its pretty stupid question since app can not print to android studio console if its not being emulated by android studio.

But if there is anyother way to catch those values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging to catch those values... logging is best idea, I can give